# How do I enable paste in textbox with Ctrl+v

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a normal `textbox` in my application.

I can paste data to it using my mouse (*Right click -> Paste*), but the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does nothing.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior is enabled by default, so the question is rather what your code does to prevent it. Do you have any `KeyDown`/`KeyUp`/`KeyPress` event handlers that may intercept the CTRL+V keystrokes?

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that [`yourTextBox.ShortcutsEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled.aspx) is set to `true`.

Comment: Note that if `ShortcutsEnabled` is `false` this also suppresses the standard context menu of the `TextBox` control, which would prevent pasting using the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue in [How do I allow CTRL-V (Paste) on a Winforms Textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876663/how-do-i-allow-ctrl-v-paste-on-a-winforms-textbox)

To quote Sandeep:

> It is because in the aplliciation ctrl+v shortcut was already
>   defined(Edit menu-> Paste). After removing this...it work fine for
>   me....Hope that it helps....