# How do I allow CTRL-V (Paste) on a Winforms Textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have several textboxes on a windows form.

I can't paste text into any of them using CTRL-V, though I can still right click and select paste.  This is pretty annoying.

I have tried this with the form's KeyPreview as both true and false. TextBox.ShortcutsEnabled is also true.

Comment: Not really related to this code if OTHER text boxes with no events do the same thing eh?

Comment: Agreed, I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Is the form in question a "child" form?

Comment: @Josh, yes it is. See my comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check to see if you have a menu on the form with a shortcut for Ctrl-V.

Comment: Bingo.  The form itself did not have a menu, but its MDI parent did.  It was the default "Edit" menu that the menu bar control provides.  I removed the Edit section from the menu and all is back to normal.

Comment: Wow.  Big Thanks on this one.  I had the same situation, the MDI parent had the short cut.

Comment: @granadaCoder: yes, it's /so/ annoying when the thing over ... there ... affects the thing down ... here.

Answer (score 12):

The following code should help:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyData == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
    (sender as Textbox).Paste();
}
```

Comment: A nice work around, but I would have to add code for Cut and Copy as well.  I'd prefer to return to default behavior.

Comment: @Josh: not in my environment. A 'v' remains a 'v', while the combination of the control and 'v' keys become a paste action.

Comment: I believe Josh confused the | and || operators

Comment: Think you should also set e.Handled to true

Comment: This solution worked for me. I made it generic in that I pointed all textboxes to the same handler. (Selected them all in form designer then went to Properties-Events) 
Yeah added e.Handled=true;
Didn't need Cut specific code.

Cntr-c some selected text in one Texbox then Cntrl-v pasted it into another. :)

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted has nothing to do with your Ctrl + V problem, that is for certain.  Not much else I can tell you unless you post some more code.

Special code should not be needed for Ctrl + V, but one guess I have is to make sure you have [`YourTextBoxId.ShortcutsEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled.aspx) set to `True`.

Comment: thanks, and I edited the question, but this should have been a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah.. I know this is answered but I thought I'd throw my 2cents in just for fun.  I also had a similar problem.  Setting the TextBox.ShortcutsEnabled value to True did nothing for me. I was surprised to see the note left by Microsoft here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled.aspx regarding this issue.  Quite interesting to say the least.

Given that, I just implemented the functionality through the key even handlers as indicated in the post by Webleeuw.

Comment: I'm up'ing this response for having a keen eye and seeing that comment.                  //The TextBox control does not support shortcut keys.//          Say what??   Nice find PunkConservative.

Answer (score 2):

I was also going thru with the same problem. after a lot of googling finally I found the solution. It is because in the aplliciation ctrl+v shortcut was already defined(Edit menu-> Paste). After removing this...it work fine for me....Hope that it helps....

Comment: That was the issue, and it happen to be on my MDI form (as mentioned elsewhere on this post by others.)

Answer (score 2):

The TextBox control does not support the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut key when the Multiline property value is true.

Comment: You are right, it says so in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Go to properties for the control:

Properties>Behaviour>Shortcuts Enabled = true

job done - will now accept default windows shortcut strokes for this control

Answer (score 1):

Go to TextBox Properties->Behavior->Allow Drop SET TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue. I have multi-line text box. It had a maximum of 1000. I could CTRL-V all day long.
I set it to 0 for unlimited. CTRL-V quit working. Rt-CLK-Paste still works though. I reset the length back, CTRL-V works again. Back to 0, CTRL-V quits.

I even put this code in to test, and it passed:

```
  private void txtBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string txtBool = txtBox.ShortcutsEnabled ? "true" : "false";
     MessageBox.Show(txtBox.Text + " " + txtBool);
  }
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can comment already assigned same shortcut to other control, from designer.cs/.vb form of your form.
In my case I solved it for menu in following way

```
//this.copyToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)
((System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control | System.Windows.Forms.Keys.C)));
```